# Error loading discovery document and blocked by CORS policy

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, keycloak, aspnetzero

I have already spent almost week on this issue and researched the various similar issue and applied but nothing works. Here is the detail of issue.
I am using the npm package "angular-oauth2-oidc 13.0.1" for OIDC authentication with **InitCodeFlow** and **loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin** with below auth config. But it throw the below errors and I have set the origin in keycloak client dashboard to specific url as well as '*'.

```
  let authConfig = new AuthConfig();
        authConfig.loginUrl = "https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/protocol/openid-connect/auth";
        authConfig.issuer = "https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/";
        authConfig.tokenEndpoint="https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/protocol/openid-connect/token"
        authConfig.skipIssuerCheck = loginProvider.additionalParams['ValidateIssuer'] === 'false';
        authConfig.clientId = loginProvider.clientId;
        authConfig.responseType = 'code';
        authConfig.redirectUri = window.location.origin + '/account/login';
        authConfig.scope = 'openid profile email';  
        authConfig.customQueryParams={'grant_type':'client_credentials'};
        //authConfig.showDebugInformation=true;   
        authConfig.strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation=false;
        return authConfig;
```

Error Message
[image: Error Message]

Response Message:

```
message: "Http failure response for https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration"
```

When open below link directly on browser then it show the configuration.
https://{Host}/realms/{realms-name}/.well-known/openid-configuration
[image]

Please post the possible solutions.
Thanks.

Comment: `Request header field pragma is not allowed`, so request header `Pragma` is your problem. Find what generates `Pragma` header - it is already deprecated.

Comment: @JanGaraj Thanks for the response. I have used the npm **angular-oauth2-oidc** for this. That library used the **Pragma** their side. Please see the attached screenshot and link of documentation:
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html
image screenshot: https://prnt.sc/V7czcgMkHHr3

Comment: What do you want to say: all token responses must contain pragma header. But your are not making response, you are making request, also your are not making token response, you are making discovery request. So linked doc doesn't apply at all.